# fatal error: 'bits/c++config.h' file not found

Tags: llvm-clang, llvm-gcc

I am getting the following error when I compile [STABILIZER](https://github.com/ccurtsinger/stabilizer):

`fatal error: 'bits/c++config.h' file not found`.

I am using `ubuntu14.04,gcc-4.`6.

Comment: I hava fixed this problem.

Comment: How'd you fix it?